# ReactJS - How can I make this option conditional?

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, flatpickr

I am working with the [FlatPickr Date/Time module](https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr) trying to implement the monthSelect plugin on only those fields that need it. How can I make the plugin option "monthSelectPlugin" line of code conditional based on a prop that I pass in?

(see comments in Flatpickrdatetime.jsx)

I get the following error with the code below. Also, I'm sure there is a better way to make one line of code conditional, and I am here for it, just not sure how.

Error:

```
Error: Flatpickrdatetime(...): Nothing was returned from render. 
This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```

Arrival / Departure page:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid, Typography, FormControl} from '@material-ui/core';    
import Flatpickrdatetime from './FormFields/Flatpickrdatetime';           

<Grid container item spacing={3}>
  <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
    <InputLabel shrink htmlFor="bootstrap-input">Arrival Date</InputLabel>
    <Flatpickrdatetime type="monthSelect" />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
    <InputLabel shrink htmlFor="bootstrap-input">Depart Date</InputLabel>
    <Flatpickrdatetime />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Flatpickrdatetime.jsx

```
/* https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/ */
import React from 'react';
import { fade, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import "flatpickr/dist/themes/light.css";
import monthSelectPlugin from "flatpickr/dist/plugins/monthSelect/index.js";
import "flatpickr/dist/plugins/monthSelect/style.css";
import "flatpickr/dist/themes/light.css";
import Flatpickr from "react-flatpickr";


export default function Flatpickrdatetime(props) {
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      display: 'flex',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
    },
    margin: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
      width:'100%'
    },
   flatpickr:{
      marginBottom:'0.25em',
      borderRadius: 4,
   }
  }));
 const classes = useStyles();
  {(() => {
    if (props.type === 'monthSelect'){
        return (
            <Flatpickr
                options={{
                    format: "m/d/Y",
                    altFormat: "m/d/Y",
                    altInput: true,
                    allowInput: true,

                    // if props.type equals monthSelect
                    plugins: [new monthSelectPlugin({shorthand: false, dateFormat: "Y-m-d", altFormat: "M Y"})]
                }}
                className={classes.flatpickr} />
        );
    }else if(props.type != 'monthSelect'){
        return (
            <Flatpickr
                options={{
                    format: "m/d/Y",
                    altFormat: "m/d/Y",
                    altInput: true,
                    allowInput: true,

                    // no plugin if props.type does not equal monthSelect
                }}
                className={classes.flatpickr} />
        );
    }else{
        return null;
    }
  })()}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your [IFFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) here `{(() => {` seems to be the problem. Why do you use it? Just remove it and leave the conditional statement and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! I swear I tried that at some point but it was throwing a different error. I believe it didn't like the 'props.type'. A new day, another try, and that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

your IFFE does return a value, but it is wrapped in a block statement and you miss your `return` Component. if you had it like below would work, but it's not neat:

```
return (() => {return something })()
```

First, I would recommend to define your `styles` outside of the component. Otherwise each rerender `makeStyles` is called unnecessary.

Second, you could abstract your options object build logic outside the render part, and avoid all that code duplication. You could [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to memorize its value. It will keep the same `options` unless `type` changes (you set as dependency).

one more thing, based on your logic `null` is never hit. It's a not reachable point, it will always render the first or second condition since if one is `true` the other is `false`.

after this you could have your component as:

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  margin: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    width:'100%'
  },
 flatpickr:{
    marginBottom:'0.25em',
    borderRadius: 4,
 }
}));

export default function Flatpickrdatetime({ type }) {
 const classes = useStyles();

  const options = useMemo(() => {
    const flatpickOps = {
      format: "m/d/Y",
      altFormat: "m/d/Y",
      altInput: true,
      allowInput: true,
    }

    if (type === 'monthSelect') {
      flatpickOps.plugins = [new monthSelectPlugin({shorthand: false, dateFormat: "Y-m-d", altFormat: "M Y"})]
    }
    return flatpickOps
  }, [type])

  return <Flatpickr options={options} className={classes.flatpickr} />
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional suggestions. Being new to React, I do appreciate them. I've moved the styles outside of the component and I will look into useMemo() which I have never heard of.